# Loading data on screen load

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I have following code, Right now `renderProductItem` is rendered with fixed `products`. I want list to be rendered on screen load. So when screen is loaded it should call an API and render the list based on API response.

I saw solutions using `state` sopmething like https://github.com/vikrantnegi/react-native-searchable-flatlist/blob/master/src/SearchableList.js but the problem is when i create `constructer` its not getting called on screen load. So i am not sure how to use `state` in my case.

I am unable to figure out how to call an API on screen load and render list once response is available.

```
export const ProductListScreen = ({ navigation, route }): React.ReactElement => {   

  const displayProducts: Product[] = products.filter(product => product.category === route.name);    

  const renderProductItem = (info: ListRenderItemInfo<Product>): React.ReactElement => (
    <Card
      style={styles.productItem}
      header={() => renderItemHeader(info)}
      footer={() => renderItemFooter(info)}
      onPress={() => onItemPress(info.index)}>
      <Text category='s1'>
        {info.item.title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        appearance='hint'
        category='c1'>
          {info.item.category}
      </Text>
          <RateBar
            style={styles.rateBar}
            value={4}
          // onValueChange={setRating}
          />
      <CategoryList
        style={styles.categoryList}
        data={["Adventure", "Sport", "Science", "XXX"]}
      />
      <Text>
        The element above represents a flex container (the blue area) with three flex items.
      </Text>
    </Card>
  );

  return (
    <List
      contentContainerStyle={styles.productList}
      data={displayProducts.length && displayProducts || products}
      renderItem={renderProductItem}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use hooks in your ProductListScreen component. You can create a state using useState hook and with the help of useEffect you achieve the behaviour of componentDidMount.

Please refer to this link:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidMount()` to display the content. In React, this is a ["lifecycle method"](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class). In the examples cited in the documentation you see that functions can be triggered when a component is added or removed. Based on your description you would want to test out `componentDidMount` for your code.

In the code sample you cited, you can see that this developer uses it in his class to call the `makeRemoteRequest` function

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=20`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.results,
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
        });
        this.arrayholder = res.results;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };
```

Comment: if i do `    componentDidMount() {

  }
` i am getting Cannot find name 'componentDidMount'.ts(2304)

Comment: Lifecycle functions like `componentDidMount` only work in class components.  The code example OP provides is clearly a functional component, not a class component.